# factoring css3 transform scale into jquery ui resizeable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css, jquery-ui-resizable

I am trying to factor in the effects of scaling an element when using jquery ui resizeable.

There are a few posts here about css3 transform issues with resize/drag... none of which I found to provide a successful solution.

I am setting aside the rotation issue for now. Just want it to work with scale.

I managed to modify the draggable, but having trouble with the resizeable.
example:

```
HTML

 <div id= 'div1'> 
resize the div and note that the mouse cursor's
distance from the resize handle increases over time
<div>

  CSS
 #div1{
  margin:100px;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 border:1px solid black;
 font-size:12pt;
 overflow:hidden;
 -webkit-transform:scale(2);
 }​​

  JS
 $('#div1').resizable();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/asaf/JBE2r/1/

Comment: note: commenting out a 'bugfix' in jquery ui 1.8.11 goes a long way to reducing the problem. but there are still issues with the cursor location relative to the element. search the ui code for: // bugfix for http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/1749

Comment: changing the source code of a library is always the very worst way of extending it for non-generic cases. :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to divide the dx and dy variables in the _mouseDarg event by the transform scale attribute. (In my case x and y transform are always the same)
I am setting the 'scaleFactor' parameter in the mousestart event.

```
    _mouseDrag: function(event) {
   console.log(this.size.height);
 var yDiff = event.pageY / this.originalMousePosition.top;
 //console.log(yDiff);

    //Increase performance, avoid regex
    var el = this.helper, o = this.options, props = {},
        self = this, smp = this.originalMousePosition, a = this.axis;

    var dx = (event.pageX-smp.left)||0, dy = (event.pageY-smp.top)||0; 
    var trigger = this._change[a];
    if (!trigger) return false;

    //NOTE adjusting dx, dy below by the transform scale factor:

    dy = dy / self.scaleFactor;
    dx = dx / self.scaleFactor;
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a solution for this problem and posted the details here:

http://gungfoo.wordpress.com/2013/02/15/jquery-ui-resizabledraggable-with-transform-scale-set/

There is no need to change the source of jquery-ui. All you needed is a callback for the `resize` event of the resizable element that adjusts for the scale factor like in CodeToads answer.

```
function resizeFix(event, ui) {
    var changeWidth = ui.size.width - ui.originalSize.width; // find change in width
    var newWidth = ui.originalSize.width + changeWidth / zoomScale; // adjust new width by our zoomScale

    var changeHeight = ui.size.height - ui.originalSize.height; // find change in height
    var newHeight = ui.originalSize.height + changeHeight / zoomScale; // adjust new height by our zoomScale

    ui.size.width = newWidth;
    ui.size.height = newHeight;
}

$(this).resizable({
    minWidth: -(contentElem.width()) * 10,  // these need to be large and negative
    minHeight: -(contentElem.height()) * 10, // so we can shrink our resizable while scaled
    resize: resizeFix
});
```